# LINQ: How to convert from ISingleResult<T> to IQueryable<int>

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I've started to convert some of my existing LINQ to SQL queries into ones that use Stored Procedures. However, the format in which results are returned is different and I was wondering if there's a clever way to convert from one format to the other.

So, for example, I've got a LINQ query that returns me a set of integers in IQueryable format:

```
public static Func<rdfsDataContext, IQueryable<int>>
              SubClasses = CompiledQuery.Compile( ( rdfsDataContext itsRdfsContext ) =>
                           itsRdfsContext.rdfs_statements.Where( s => s.predicate == kSubClassId )
                           .Select( s => s.subject ) );
```

When using Store Procedures, again called via LINQ, the returned format is:

```
 ISingleResult<SubClassesResult> subClasses = itsRdfsContext.SubClasses( kSubClassId );
```

Where SubClassesResult is a class that is auto generated by the LINQ system and that only contains a single property, an integer called "Subject".

Is there any simple way to get the result that is returned from the Stored Procedure from this ISingleResult< SubClassesResult > format into the IQueryable< int > format that I had previously?

Comment: This might help - it's an article on table valued functions in LINQ to SQL:  http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/05/21/table-valued-functions-in-linq-to-sql.aspx

Comment: @Tim, that's perfect thank you. Using the table valued function allowed me to get an IQueryable<T> which I could then use a Select( s => s.subject ) to get to the what I was after, the IQueryable<int>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
 subclasses.Select(a=>a.Subject).AsQueryable();
```

?

Comment: this works! plus it has the advantage that I don't need to switch from using Stored Procedures to Table-valued functions.